# UITextView did end editing

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, textview, uitextview

I would like to `NSLog` something when my UITextView is done editing.

I've tried

`- (BOOL)textViewShouldEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

and

`- (void)textViewDidEndEditing:(UITextView *)textView`

neither worked.

fix:

`myTextView.delegate = self;`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

do you set the delegate of your textview?

fix:

set delegate in .h file like this:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>  

@interface TextViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>  
{  
          UITextView *textView;  
}  
@property (nonatomic, retain) UITextView *textView;  
@end
```

Comment: and don't forget the delegate setting in .h file

Comment: How can I set it in the .h file?

Comment: @interface ViewController : UIViewController <UITextViewDelegate>

Answer (score 2):

If you are using UITextField instead make sure to use UITextFieldDelegate and not UITextViewDelegate. And this method instead, that fixed my problems.

```
- (void)textFieldDidEndEditing:(UITextField *)textField
```